# MYSQL query, combine records irrelevant tables for autocomplete

Tags: android, mysql, sql

I m trying to create an autocomplete search for my android application. I m using mysql database for this. I want to search three column bu one of the column is on other table. I have 2 table . There are a1 , a2 column in first table and there is username column in second table. I want to search from two table and combine this records for my autocomplete search list. I want to accomplish like this ;

```
SELECT   *  
FROM     table1 t1, 
         table2 t2 
WHERE    t1.a1  LIKE '%er%' 
OR       t1.a2  LIKE '%er%' 
OR       t2.username LIKE '%er%
```

I don't want combine related records I want irrelevant records from two tables to one table.

Not : Columns of tables are diffrent from each other.

Please help me about this MYSQL query.

Comment: please post some sample data and the expected result

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that like this, while the columns are different. Otherwise UNION would be an idea... I think you have to use multiple queries...